# Ровный треугольник с равными сторонами

Tags: android, геометрия

Создал кастомную вью для индикации Expandable в виде треугольника, но стороны не одной длины. Как исправить?

```
public class ExpandableTriangleView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;
    private boolean isExpanded;

    public ExpandableTriangleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public void expand() {
        isExpanded = true;
        path = null;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void collapse() {
        isExpanded = false;
        path = null;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(getTrianglePath(), paint);
    }

    private Path getTrianglePath() {
        if (path == null) {
            path = new Path();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            if (isExpanded) {
                path.moveTo(0, 0);
                path.lineTo(width, 0);
                path.lineTo(width / 2, height);
            } else {
                path.moveTo(0, 0);
                path.lineTo(0, height);
                path.lineTo(width, height / 2);
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы как в Android Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте стрелочка с одинаковой длиной сторон, а у меня третья вершина (которая указывает направление) отдалена от основания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создается View треугольника с одинаковыми сторонами

```
int triangleWidth = Utils.dpToPx(10);
expandableTriangle = new ExpandableTriangleView(getContext());
LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams triangleParams = new MarginLayoutParams(triangleWidth, triangleWidth);
triangleParams.rightMargin = leftPadding;
directoryView.addView(expandableTriangle, triangleParams);
```

Comment: Какие значения для высоты и ширины используете?

Comment: @Эникейщик, дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для равностороннего:

```
            path.moveTo(0, 0);
            path.lineTo(width, 0);
            path.lineTo(width / 2, width * Sqrt(3)/ 2);
```

и аналогично для другой ориентации

Comment: Супер, спасибо!